# imageView UITapGestureRecognizer in a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to add a tap gesture on an `imageView`, inside a `tableView cell`.
The problem is if I put the gesture code in the `cellForRow`, it doesn't recognise the url, and off course all the images get the url of the last cell.
if I put the gesture code in the `didSelect`, the url always gets null, I think because the gesture is working before the cell gets it data.

**the imageView should open a video file, based on its url, that gets it from an XML parser.**

```
selectedArticle = [self getArticleAtIndex:indexPath];
UIImageView* imageTap = [          
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                 initWithTarget:self
                                                 action:@selector(actionHandleTapOnImageView)];
            [singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
            imageTap.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            [imageTap addGestureRecognizer:singleTap]

(void)actionHandleTapOnImageView{
    NSString *path = selectedArticle.videoUrl;
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *theArticle = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:theArticle];
    theArticle.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    [theArticle.moviePlayer play];
}
```

Comment: You should probably be adding the gesture recogniser in the CustomCell class, was there any specific reason for using cellForRow?

Comment: no specific reason. kind of new in the programming world, and most of the things are new for me. i'll try to add the gesture in the customCell, but I think that the problem won't change- the url will be null as long as it wont get the data.

Comment: initialize it in awakeFromNib, in the cell have a property for your article and in cellForRow set it there. Then you shouldnt have any problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's better to add a button instead of an imageview. The code should look somehow like this:

```
// in cell for row:
UIButton *buttonImage = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
buttonImage.frame = CGRectMake(5.0, 5.0, 40.0, 40.0);
buttonImage.tag = indexPath.row;
[buttonImage setBackgroundImage:yourImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttonImage addTarget:self action:@selector(imageTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell addSubview:buttonImage];
```

Then in `imageTap`:

```
- (void)imageTap:(UIButton *)sender
{
    selectedArticle = [self getArticleAtIndex:sender.tag];
    NSString *path = selectedArticle.videoUrl;
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *theArticle = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:theArticle];
    theArticle.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    [theArticle.moviePlayer play];
}
```

This approach will prevent you from some side effects of using tap recognizers in table cells. And it's easy to understand and correct.